# link to Print in a webpage

Tags: browser, printing, html

Can I put a link on my webpage to the Printer ?

To go to the same page like Ctrl-P goes in Firefox, IE.

Thank you.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:if(window.print)window.print()">Print</a>
```

Comment: Is there a similar way to print another URL in this fashion? (As opposed to the current one.) For example a list where each line represents a file and each line contains a print button/link. (So you could print the destination file before actually visiting the link and going to that page.)

Comment: The simplest way I can think of involves opening the page you want to print in a new window, and that page doing `window.print(); window.close()`. But perhaps there's a simpler way I don't know about. Try asking as a new top level question.

Answer (score 11):

Add this to your link:

```
onclick="window.print();"
```